# Secure method for allowing users to remotely execute SSIS package

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I've been tasked with creating a somewhat automated process that allows a non-SQL user to import data from an Excel spreadsheet into a table in SQL Server. We currently use SQL Server 2012. The user needs to be able to upload data whenever they finish putting it together in an Excel spreadsheet. I have created an SSIS package that checks a specific folder on a shared drive for the file. If the file exists it then goes through some transformations and is then inserted into the final table in the database. The user only really needs to do this a handful of times a year but we never know when so they want to give the user the ability to do this whenever they need to. I am at the point where I need to find a way to either allow the user to execute the package or start a job that executes the package remotely for their computer. I don't want to use anything that uses xp_cmdshell as I've heard this can create unnecessary vulnerabilities. I've read that I can use Reporting Services to execute the package but I'm not sure if this is secure or the best way to go. Microsoft says that it's possible but is not supported or recommended at this time https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345250.aspx . I'm wondering if I can do this in C# without having to store credentials in plain text since the user doesn't have database access. Microsoft has an article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/run-manage-packages-programmatically/loading-and-running-a-remote-package-programmatically) on remotely running an SSIS package using Integrated Security but the user wouldn't have access. I'm also not entirely opposed to using Reporting Services if someone has experience doing it this way and can speak on whether or not this would be the best way to go. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are so many problems here it is just too much for an online forum. Aside from the challenges you already are dealing with you need to handle invalid data from the user. This typically means loading data to a staging table and then attempting the insert into the real tables.

Comment: The data is put into a staging table prior to being inserted into the final table. I will be providing the user with an Excel template that they must use for it to work. Should the user still find some way to mess up the data load, I will be alerted so I can see what they have done wrong.

Comment: Since this is an excel file that you say is a template what about putting in a button with a macro to insert the data with VBA? Or create a service that receives a file? I would probably lean heavily towards the service side to keep all the programming logic with the IT folks and not in the hands of "the general population".

Comment: Can you not just schedule the SSIS package to run on regular basis from the SQL Server Agent? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/220/scheduling-ssis-packages-with-sql-server-agent/

Comment: I would say create a batch file and ask user to execute it in local server instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to address the SSRS specific part of this question since you've asked directly about this option.

It is possible to [execute an SSIS package via T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-tsql-ssms) if connected to the SSISDB database using code like this:

```
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Package.dtsx',
    @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
    @folder_name=N'Deployed Projects',
      @project_name=N'Integration Services Project1',
    @use32bitruntime=False,
      @reference_id=Null
Select @execution_id
DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,
    @object_type=50,
      @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL',
      @parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
GO
```

Because SSRS allows you to execute a stored procedure from a dataset, you can put any type of SQL logic into that dataset and have it execute, including something like this.  How fancy you want to get with the report is up to you, as you could have a button on the report that actually executes the package instead of just running the package on the first report run. You would need to use a parameter on report load with a default value that you check in your T-SQL and bypass the package execution, depending on the value.  Because your credentials are stored in a regular SSRS data source, this should be considered as secure as the rest of your reporting databases

Note, a nicer and cleaner way to do this would be to have a web app developer create a very simple application that allows authorized users to execute the T-SQL command.  The SSRS option may be considered a bit hacky since reports are not meant for running commands and modifying data, more as a display method for data. However, I've been in large organizations where you are tasked with a problem like this and not given the latitude to use any "better" tools so this is at least an option.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I just wanted to let everyone know that we went ahead with using SSRS to run the SSIS package using the code @Daniel provided and everything is working great!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you can select the green checkmark to mark it as an accepted answer for future people